# Dealing with missing data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel 2013 Line Chart. The Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels are set to "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018".
I create multiple Legend Entries (Series) successfully, i.e. series with values for each of these years. I try to also add a series which only has data for "2016", "2017", "2018", but the series is inserted into the chart as if these were values for "2014", "2015", "2016" and series line on the chart simply ends after "2016". Is there any way to have this series' line start at"2016" and continue onward which would be correct for its data? I could insert fake 0 values, but then the line would shoot up from 0 to its 2016 which would distort the graph, etc. I simply want the line to start at "2016", that's all.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the graph you are referring too?

Comment: To reproduce the situation we need sample data !